# How to use Code Igniter to show Dynamic images via javascript(jQuery)

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, urlhelper

You can use the URL helper in Code Igniter to load CSS and Javascript with the base_url() method, but what if you have images dynamically being placed into your HTML via javascript? for example in my javascript file I've got

```
var arrowimages={down:['downarrowclass', 'images/down.png', 23], right:['rightarrowclass', 'images/right.png']}
```

and those images will be placed into whatever menu item I've specified has a drop down menu.

but that file is a .js file so obviously the server won't load php inside of it.

so, how can I set the base url for the JS?

Thanks!

-Aaron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a constant javascript variable like `BASE_URI` in the  of your view, you can then reference this variable in any of your external javascript files.

```
<head>
....
<script type="text/javascript">
    var BASE_URI = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>";
</script>
....
</head>
```

External js...

```
var arrowimages={down:['downarrowclass', BASE_URI+'images/down.png', 23], right:['rightarrowclass', BASE_URI+'images/right.png']}
```